Select random rows and copy to other sheet
The macro below randomly selects one row and copies to different sheet. How can I get the macro to select randomly multiple rows and copy to different sheet?
Sub CopyRandom()

    Sheets("Sheet13").Select
    Range("A15:I50").Select
    Selection.Clear
    
    Sheets("GB-151").Select
    
    Dim PopulationSelect As Range
    Set PopulationSelect = Range("A9:A346")
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long
    Set r = PopulationSelect

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 14
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(nFirstRow, nLastRow)
    Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Select
    
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet13").Select
    Range("A15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

Copied one random row as expected but cannot get to copy multiple random rows.

What does "multiple random rows" mean? 3, 5, 36, or 338?

Here's one approach:
Sub CopyRandomRows()
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, i As Long
    Dim col As New Collection, n As Long
    
    Set rngSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GB-151").Range("A9:I346") 'source range
    Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("A15")   'first paste range
    rngDest.Resize(45, 9).Clear                    'clear any previous data from paste area
    
    For i = 1 To rngSrc.Rows.Count 'fill collection with potential row numbers
        col.Add i
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To 20 'pick(eg) 20 random rows
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, col.Count) 'random item from collection
        With rngSrc.Rows(col.item(i)) 'the selected row...
            rngDest.Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value 'copy chosen row (A:I)
        End With
        col.Remove i  'remove the selected index from the collection to prevent re-selection
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1) 'next paste position
    Next n
End Sub


Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
